# Symmetry breaking in the compressed column buckling

Tags: simulations, symmetry-breaking

When a compressed slender column buckles, how does the symmetry break and the beams chooses a specific plane to buckle; The differential eq. solution only describes the mode (shape ) of the buckle but not the direction into which it happens. In its simpler form in a 2D horizontal beam configuration, compressed from both ends, there are 2 directions to buckle (up and down) and the solution of the DE says nothing about the direction this happens .Can the direction be specified somehow mathematically? In the real world of course tiny  perturbations  preclude the existence of the absolutely symmetrical case.I understand that there is no way to "choose" one of the two solutions as the solution( in 2D case ) ,But what about simulation? When simulating such a system is the output of such a simulator random? (Up 50% down 50%)?

Answer (score 0):

You will find in the derivations for the "classical" case of slender column buckling,  the stability of the system is examined against perturbations of order ~small compared to the aspect ratio of the column. If the perturbation grows without bound then buckling is declared at whatever the compressive load and perturbation magnitude was.

Unless the simulation software can be explicitly directed to include perturbation stability analysis, the outcome of the simulation can't be predicted.